# Convert multiple Unicode in a string to character

Tags: regex, string, perl, unicode

Problem -- I have a string, say `Buna$002C_TexasBuna$002C_Texas`' and where `$` is followed by Unicode. I want to replace these Unicode with its respective Unicode character representation.

In [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) if any Unicode is in the form of "`\x{002C}` then it will be converted to it respective Unicode character. Below is the sample code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $string = "Hello \x{263A}!\n";
@arr= split //,$string;
print "@arr";
```

I am processing a file which contain 10 million of records. So I have these strings in a scalar variable. To do the same as above I am substituting `$4_digit_unicode` to `\x{4_digit_unicode}` as below.

```
$str = 'Buna$002C_TexasBuna$002C_Texas';
$str =~s/\$(.{4})/\\x\{$1\}/g;
$str = "$str"
```

It gives me

```
Buna\x{002C}_TexasBuna\x{002C}_Texas
```

It is because at `$str = "$str"`, line `$str` is being interpolated, but not its value. So `\x{002C}` is not being interpolated by Perl.

Is there a way to force Perl so that it will also interpolate the contents of `$str` too?

OR

Is there another method to achieve this? I do not want to take out each of the Unicodes then pack it using `pack "U4",0x002C` and then substitute it back. But something in one line (like the below unsuccessful attempt) is OK.

```
$str =~ s/\$(.{4})/pack("U4",$1)/g;
```

I know the above is wrong; but can I do something like above?

For the input string `$str = 'Buna$002C_TexasBuna$002C_Texas'`, the desired output is `Buna,_TexasBuna,_Texas`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This gives the desired result:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $str = 'Buna$002C_TexasBuna$002C_Texas';

$str =~s/\$(.{4})/chr(hex($1))/eg;

say $str;
```

The main interesting item is the `e` in `s///eg`. The `e` means to treat the replacement text as code to be executed. The `hex()` converts a string of hexadecimal characters to a number. The `chr()` converts a number to a character. The replace line might be better written as below to avoid trying to convert a dollar followed by non-hexadecimal characters.

```
$str =~s/\$([0-9a-f]{4})/chr(hex($1))/egi;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute statements such as `pack` in the replacement string, you just have to use the `e` regular expression modifier.

Or you can do this

```
$str =~s/\$(.{4})/"@{[pack("U4",$1)]}/g;
```

If those two options don't work please let me know, take a look at this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3250942/439667) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

`"\x{263A}"` (quotes included) is a string literal, a piece of *code* that produces a string containing the lone character `263A` when it's *evaluated* by the interpreter (by being part of the script passed to `perl` to be evaluated).

`"\\x\{$1\}"` (quotes included), on the other hand, produces a string consisting of `\`, `x`, `{`, the contents of `$1`, and `}`.

The latter is the string you are producing. You appear to be attempting to produce Perl code, but it's not valid Perl code -- it's missing the quotes -- and you never have the code interpreted by `perl`.

---

```
 $str =~ s/\$(.{4})/\\x\{$1\}/g;
```

is short for

```
 $str =~ s/\$(.{4})/ "\\x\{$1\}" /eg;
```

which is completely different than

```
 $str =~ s/\$(.{4})/ "\x{263A}" /eg;
```

---

It looks like you were going for the following:

```
$str =~ s/\$(.{4})/ eval qq{"\\x\{$1\}"} /eg;
```

But there are much simpler ways of producing the desired string, such as

```
$str =~ s/\$(.{4})/ pack "U4", $1 /eg;
```

or better yet,

```
$str =~ s/\$(.{4})/ chr hex $1 /eg;
```